# Java client for time server, such as Network Time Protocol (NTP)

Tags: java

Looking for a **time-server client library for Java**. I suppose means only [*Network Time Protocol (NTP)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).

My goal is simply to fetch the current date-time from a time server. I will compare to verify the accuracy of the host computer’s clock.

Any reliable NTP client would do I imagine, as I cannot think of any features to specify here. One feature to consider might be secure connections, to ensure the reported time is not altered in transit.

If there are other time server protocols, enlighten me.